# Comparison of two rows in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

Good Day

I have the following result set returned:

```
financeYearEnd          FromDate    ToDate      ClientPortfolioCode
2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 2014-01-01  2014-01-31  C1
2013-12-31 00:00:00.000 2014-01-01  2014-01-31  C2
2012-12-31 00:00:00.000 2013-12-01  2013-12-31  C1
2012-12-31 00:00:00.000 2013-12-01  2013-12-31  C2
```

What I need to do is the following:

I need to compare the financeYearEnd of all the C1 Fields (there will always only be two), and see if they are different to each other

```
 2013-12-31 00:00:00.000    2014-01-01  2014-01-31  C1
 2012-12-31 00:00:00.000    2013-12-01  2013-12-31  C1
```

As seen, the financeYearEnd does differ, so I need to store that result as a row in a temporary Table.

This needs to be done for all distinct ClientPortfolioCodes(Which will always appear in groups of two)

How can this be achieved?

I have tried `select distinct ..` - didn't work. It returned all my rows

EDIT -

```
WITH cteCompareTopTwoYears
AS (
    SELECT TOP (
            SELECT COUNT(*) * 2
            FROM #ClientPortFolios
            ) FinancialYearEnd AS financeYearEnd
        ,FromDate
        ,ToDate
        ,CA.ClientPortfolioCode
    FROM rpt.F3_fn_ClientPortfolios_CapitalAccount_IncludingYTD CA
    WHERE (
            (
                CA.FromDate = (DATEADD(m, - 1, @FromDate))
                AND CA.ToDate = (DATEADD(m, - 1, @ToDate))
                )
            OR (
                CA.FromDate = @FromDate
                AND CA.ToDate = @ToDate
                )
            )
        AND (
            CA.ClientPortFolioCode IN (
                SELECT ClientPortfolioCode
                FROM #ClientPortfolios
                )
            )
    ORDER BY FromDate DESC
    )
SELECT *
FROM cteCompareTopTwoYears c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`, e.g.:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT financeYearEnd, FromDate, ToDate, ClientPortfolioCode,
           rn = row_Number () OVER (Partition By ClientPortfolioCode
                                    Order By financeYearEnd ASC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT financeYearEnd, FromDate, ToDate, ClientPortfolioCode
FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fc2a/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: That's just the thing. I generated that table from a CTE. Will post now.

Comment: I have posted the CTE Where the table's information is retrieved

Comment: my little brain didn't catch the partition by part for the first few minutes, after that I went through numerous books and online resources. I ... feel enlightened.  thanks